# UWP - Changing a property value using EventTriggerBehavior and ChangePropertyAction when the page is loaded

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a page with a master detail pattern. In the left side, there is a ListView and in the right side, there are some TextBlocks showing information about the ListView's SelectedItem. When the page is loaded, there is not any selected item at the beginning, therefore the textblocks on the right side are blank. But I would like to show some initial text when there is not any selected item. So I did something like the following (I suppressed some code for clarity):

```
<Page>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Description}" PropertyName="Text" Value="It works!" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    ........
    <TextBlock x:Name="Description" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItem.Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
</Page>
```

But it doesn't work. The textblocks remain blank. How can I achieve what I want?

By the way, I'm following the MVVM pattern so I'm trying to reduce the code-behind as much as possible but I will put that logic in the code-behind if there is not other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach `ChangePropertyAction` to your TextBlock instead. The load of the page doesn't guarantee the load of the TextBlock.

```
<TextBlock ...>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Description}" PropertyName="Text" Value="It works!" />
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```